# Invoking custom class methods with WCF Request

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Is there any way to invoke another class method while invoking request methods in Post Request Of WCF? If there is how to do it and I also want the model attributes in that custom class method.

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved by wcf.

Comment: @TheobaldDu is there any other way around? I really need to do this.

Comment: You can take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261696/how-do-i-pass-a-custom-class-to-a-wcf-service